# Laravel Input::file returning empty array while $_FILES has data

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4

To keep it simple, I have this in my view:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'files', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => 'true']) }}
{{ Form::file('file') }}
{{ Form::submit(); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And in my controller:

```
return Response::json([$_FILES, print_r(Input::file('file'),1)]);
```

This is the response I get when I submit:

```
[
    {
        "file": {
            "name": "sample.jpg",
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "tmp_name": "/tmp/phpItZT7K",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 17645
        }
    },
    {}
]
```

The only real solutions I've come across while searching is the enctype, which I have on my form via the 'files' attribute in Form::open. At this point, I have no idea what's going on. It's not application-breaking, but it's still annoying. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd be very happy.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing...??

Comment: Input::file() was returning no data. No UploadedFile object or anything. It has since then magically started working again between refreshes without my changing any code that was relevant, or so I believe.

Comment: We are having the same problem. $_FILES shows an array with the file but Input::file('file') is showing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't clarified what the actual problem is but I am guessing it's the `Input::file()` not coming through the JSON. That's because `Input::file()` returns a [symfony object](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) which can't be encoded so you would have to create your own array.

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$output = ['name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(), 'size' => $file->getClientSize()]; // etc
```

Comment: I'm was using print_r(Input::file('file'),1) to print in the JSON output, and it was always blank. I just forgot to include that in the post.

Comment: Try using the Log class to log the object and see what happens. Are you actually clicking the button or using AJAX?